# What do I need to look for in good, quality hiking boots?

Tags: hiking, boots, clothing

My wife and I are going to buy some hiking boots as we've been using regular tennis shoes anytime we go on a hike.

What are the things I need to keep in mind when looking for a good set of **quality** hiking boots (materials, type etc)?

We generally go temperate hiking, so don't need something that protects against terrible cold. Also, we do walk along rivers and occasionally will get wet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- **Correct size**. That might sound obvious, but consider also width and height (of the instep). Each make is a bit different, so there's a need to try on many before you find one that fits really good. For all-day trips get boots one size larger than your usual office shoes are.
- **Vibram sole**
- If properly maintained, **leather upper** is much more waterproof and durable than fabric/suede. Unfortunately, it is also heavier.
- The fewer seams the better. Boots with many seams, holes etc. usually are not very waterproof :)
- **Gore-Tex** inside is a big plus. Especially for multi day hikes in wet weather, when shoes won't fully dry overnight.

Comment: Why Vibram sole? It's just a brand name. I don't see these being particuarly any better than any other brand

Comment: Sure there are other good makes. However, based on my expereince I would still say Vibram is a safe bet. I found it doing well especially on slippery surfaces.

Comment: FYI: My understanding of vibram is most manufactures use their soles basically because it's cheaper to outsource this to a company that only makes soles, they have the machinery so we don't have to buy it kinda thing. I don't believe they do anything special when compared to a boot manufacturer making their own soles, it's just more cost effective to outsource it.

Answer (score 14):

My experience in this field is quite limited, but this is what I'd look for:

- **Light** - Hiking boots should be as light as possible. Believe me when I say that walking around when carrying a ton sucks.
- **A proper sole** - and by proper I mean one that isn't too hard or too soft. Too hard will provide little to no traction on slippery surfaces, and one that is too soft will wear out quickly.
- **Water resistant** - It would be hard to speak of *water-proof*, but hiking boots should definitely be water resistant. A quick slip should not render your feet completely wet.

And as a sidenote, do wear those boots in before a long hike. And if there is little time, carry some duct-tape, as was mentioned in this [article](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-treat-hot-spots-blisters-when-i-have-no-moleskin).

Comment: If you live in a very hot, but dry area, water resistant might not be as required, and might make the shoe too warm.

Comment: Re wearing in a pair of boots -- modern materials have in most cases made this idea obsolete. You have materials in your boots like kevlar. They don't give, and they don't wear in. You simply have to buy the right size.

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure you need boots? I absolutely love my trail running shoes ([La Sportiva Wildcats](http://www.sportiva.com/products/footwear/mountain-running/wildcat)). They are much lighter than  boots, and while they aren't water proof, they dry out very quickly due to being mostly mesh uppers. On hot days, you can literally feel the breeze through the uppers. It is very nice for me as my feet tend to sweat a lot in boots.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like some boots mainly for the extra support when navigating boulders and such. +1 For the link though. I'll check them out.

Comment: @justnS: Plenty of people get along fine on boulder-ish terrain in running shoes. It's a matter of taste.