# How do I prevent blisters in ski boots?

Tags: gear, skiing, backcountry, blisters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I treat hot spots and blisters when I have no moleskin?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-treat-hot-spots-and-blisters-when-i-have-no-moleskin)
>   [How do I treat a blister? How can I prevent getting them in the first place?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/157/how-do-i-treat-a-blister-how-can-i-prevent-getting-them-in-the-first-place)

I often get blisters in my ski touring boots in the instep of my feet. I've tried thick and thin insoles and multiple pairs of socks but that didn't work. What else can I do to prevent blisters in my ski boots?

Comment: I'm not convinced snow boots are significantly different from hiking boots as far as blister prevention goes. Reduce friction and keep your feet dry.

Comment: I agree with @TimothyStrimple and would also add that especially for ski touring, I find that using silk socks as my 1st sock can be a boon. Always putting socks on right before stepping into boots helps as well since it reduces sweat accumulation before you're at the mtn.